# JQuery addClass() on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to build a Jquery/CSS drop down menu and things have been going pretty good so far. I'm pretty new to JQuery and I get it most of the time - however, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I am attempting to change the class of one of the drop-down tabs when it is clicked, but it doesn't appear to be working as expected.

You can see the code I have so far over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/utdream/NZJXq/

I have the class "selected" looking how I want the button to look when a button is clicked on, but I cannot seem to make it so the "selected" class is applied on a click event. In theory, this:

```
<li id="menuProducts"><a href="#" class="hasmore">Products</a>
    <div id="ProductsMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Should change this this on a click event:

```
<li id="menuProducts"><a href="#" class="selected">Products</a>
    <div id="ProductsMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

And this is my current jQuery (which doesn't work):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#menuProducts a:first').on('click',
    function () {
        $("a:first").removeClass("hasmore");
        $("a:first").addClass("selected");
        menuSubCloseAll.call(this, 'menuProducts');
        $('#menuProducts').find('li').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

I've tried rewriting this code in many,many different ways and I'm running out of ideas on what I could be doing wrong.

Anyone out there have any pointers on what I could do to fix this?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: change `$("a:first")` with `$(this)`.

Comment: lol ::facepalm:: thanks Omar.

Comment: a comment is faster than an answer and safer ;) welcome buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#menuProducts a:first').on('click',
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hasmore");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        menuSubCloseAll.call(this, 'menuProducts');
        $('#menuProducts').find('li').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

You were actually changing the class of the first `<a>` in your page, not the `<a>` you clicked, which you can access directly in the handler with `$(this)` .

Comment: Thanks Nelson. Geez. I can't believe I missed that! =P

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use "this" inside the call??

```
$('#menuProducts a:first').on('click',
        function () {
           $(this).removeClass("hasmore");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            menuSubCloseAll.call(this, 'menuProducts');
            $('#menuProducts').find('li').slideToggle(200);
        });
```

It worked for me